# Quine "Ontological Relativity"

Tags: quine

I am completely new to Quine's theories and thank you for your patience in answering my novice questions.

In his paper "Ontological Relativity", Quine says:

> Consider the case of a thoughtful protosyntactician. He has a formalized system of first-order proof theory, or protosyntax, whose universe comprises just expressions, that is, strings of signs of a specified alphabet. Now just what sorts of things, more specifically, are these expressions? They are
>   types, not tokens. So, one might suppose, each of them is the set of all its tokens. That is, each expression is a set of inscriptions which are variously situated in space-time but are classed together by virtue of a certain similarity in shape.
>   The concatenate x~y of two expressions x and y, in a given order, will be the set of all inscriptions each of which has two parts which are tokens respectively of x and y and follow one upon the other in that order. But x ~ y may then be the null set, though x and yare not null; for it may be that inscriptions belonging to x and y happen to turn up head to tail nowhere, in the past, present, or future. This danger increases with the lengths of x and y. But it is easily seen to violate a law of proto syntax which says that x = z whenever x ~ y = z ~ y.

**Why does x ~ y being a null set violate the law of protosyntax?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Frankly speaking, what I can imagine is this*...

With *concatenation* we can form an expression **x⌢y** that has never been used (and never will be), and thus it is a [type](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/types-tokens/) with no tokens, i.e. the null set.

If the same happens with **z⌢y**, we have that **x⌢y=z⌢y**, because both are the null set.

But **x** and **z** may be two different expressions, i.e. **x ≠ z**.

This violates the [laws of syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Formal_definition) because if two expressions are equal and they have the same *tail*, their *heads* must be equal.